# Measuring the effect of spin of a tennis ball on its trajectory

Tags: classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, rotational-dynamics, rotation

Upward spin (lift) applied to a tennis ball will shorten its trajectory.
Are mathematical calculations and actual experimental results on this available somewhere?
If not, does anyone know how to relate the ball's rotation speed to the (modified/distorted) parabola of its trajectory?
My thinking is that there must be a way to relate the speed of rotation of the ball to the change of a,b,c in the parabola equation $y = ax^2 + bx +c$ that - I suppose - describes a spinless ball trajectory.

Comment: "Lift" is usually known as top spin.

Comment: [Review of tennis ball aerodynamics](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/jst.11) might help?

Comment: @Farcher Thank you, I will look at it. My goal is to be able to obtain a function describing the ball trajectory (expressed in meters) as a function of its top spin (expressed in rpm), all other parameters being equal (height at which the ball is hit etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Two papers available from researchgate.net are very enlighting :

Sarafian, H. (2015) Impact of the Drag Force and the Magnus Effect on the Trajectory of a Baseball.
World Journal of Mechanics, 5, 49-58. http://dx.doi.org/10.4236/wjm.2015.54006

Zihang Ding, Shiheng Jiang, Xiao Wang, Zhijie Wei.
The Influence of Magnus Effect on The Flying Distance of Baseball and Golf.
Highlights in Science, Engineering and Technology TPCEE 2022
Volume 38 (2023) 821.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).